# css drop down menu - "hiding" nested menu items

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a drop down menu, however I'm having difficulty "hiding" the nested menu items. The links and styling work fine, it's just the drop-down effect that I've missed something on. Ideas?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cScrD/)

css-

```
#header .social {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#header .social ul li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

#header .social ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

#header .social ul li a {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#header .social ul li:hover ul {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
}

#header .social ul li:hover li {
    float: none;
}
```

html/php-

```
<div class="social">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/instagram.png" alt="cait and shannon barker instagram" /></a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://instagram.com/caitbarkerr/">cait</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://instagram.com/shannonbarkerr/">shannon</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/youtube.png" alt="cait and shannon barker youtube" /></a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/caitbarker">cait</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/shannonbarker">shannon</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/facebook.png" alt="cait and shannon barker facebook" /></a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/CaitShannonBarker">cait</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/CaitShannonBarker">shannon</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/twitter.png" alt="cait and shannon barker twitter" /></a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/caitbarkerr">cait</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/shannonbarkerr">shannon</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/pinterest.png" alt="cait and shannon barker lockerz" /></a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://lockerz.com/u/caitbarker">cait</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://lockerz.com/u/shannonbarker">shannon</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end social -->
```

Comment: Make whatever drops down go -9999px to the left, and on hover of the parent element, bring it back 9999px to the right.

Comment: @user2406160 What?  Just find the things you want to hide and do a `display:none`.  You have very little to go off of here.  Please show us a fiddle or image or something

Comment: @ntgCleaner fiddle added

Comment: @ntgCleaner I think it's quite obvious what I meant... if you do left:-9999px; it will go off the page, then on hover you can do right:9999px; and it will bring it back... I hope that's not too hard to understand.

Comment: `ul` is an **invalid** child of `ul`.

Comment: @Sourabh I've pieced this together from various blog posts and tutorials. Can you explain "ul is an invalid child of ul"?

Comment: Inside first `ul` you did this: `<li> <a> ... </a> </li> <ul> </ul>`. I think you meant `<li> <a> ... </a> <ul> </ul> </li>`

Comment: @user2406160 Oh, don't worry, I get what you're doing.  I'm trying to understand what you're thinking by doing that.  It could cause a lot of problems with the width of the page on certain browsers.  There are possible other problems, like having to make a different position like if it's relative, it will still save a space for it, etc.  It's not ideal

Comment: According to HTML5 rules, `li` is only valid child of `ul` or `ol`. If  you want to nest `ul`s then add the nested `ul` inside `li`. Something like this maybe... http://jsfiddle.net/cScrD/1/  look at HTML part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ? http://jsfiddle.net/cScrD/3/

The HTML structure was not standard (`ul` should not be ideally put as a child of another `ul`. Rather open an `li` tag and put the `ul` inside the `li`). The structure should ideally be like this.

```
<div id="header">
<div class="social">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/instagram.png" alt="cait and shannon barker instagram" /></a><!-- li should not end here -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://instagram.com/caitbarkerr/">cait</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://instagram.com/shannonbarkerr/">shannon</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li><!-- li should end here -->
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```